# Why does Ruby Time.at() only return 01/01/2000 inside Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, timestamp

I've got a tiny Sinatra app running on Heroku, and it has a method that receives a POST and creates a database object with the parameters of the POST.

One of those params is a timestamp of the form "1432565475.000007".  I want that as a date & time in the database, so I added a column, then in the method that handles the post I have:

```
e.time = Time.at params["timestamp"].to_f
```

The times come out correctly, but the dates are all Jan 1, 2000.

If I run irb at heroku ("heroku run irb") and try the above line of code manually it converts correctly.  It's only when it's running inside my server instance that it interprets the calendar date wrong.

So then I created a view that just iterates through the db, converting the original timestamp (I also have that in a column) into dates.  The idea being that this is more closely approximating the code that handles the POST:

```
-MyEvent.all.each do |me|
    %p
        =Time.at me.timestamp.to_i
```

And that works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the field type about the added column?

Comment: I think when you are trying to save the dates in DB, for some reason its not getting saved and saving the default dates in column.

Comment: Gah....that was it.  Yes, my column was "time" not "datetime".  I just tested datetime and it works.  Thanks.